# Simple Injector - difficulty with ASP.NET 5 Identity and RavenDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, simple-injector

I am attempting to use `SimpleInjector` with `ASP.NET 5` on an `MVC` application, and am running into a major problem getting it wired up right.

I run a `RavenDB` database, and as such I have methods for instantiating instances to it, which is what I use when registering the interfaces, like this;

```
private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app) {

    container.CrossWire<IUserStore<AppUser>>(app);
    container.CrossWire<UserManager<AppUser>>(app);
    container.CrossWire<SignInManager<AppUser>>(app);
    container.CrossWire<ILoggerFactory>(app);

    container.Register<IDocumentStore>(RavenDatabase.OpenDatabase);

    container.Register<IDocumentSession>(RavenDatabase.OpenSession);

    container.Register<IAsyncDocumentSession>(RavenDatabase.OpenAsyncSession);

    container.Register<ILookupNormalizer>(() => new LowerInvariantLookupNormalizer());

    container.Register<IPasswordHasher<AppUser>>(() => new PasswordHasher<AppUser>());
}
```

The problem seems to be with `IUserStore`. When I try to load up the application, I get this exception..

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession' while attempting to activate 'App.Identity.UserStore`1[App.Identity.AppUser]'.

I'm really uncertain why this is, though. I've registered `IAsyncDocumentSession`, so why can't it inject it? I've also tried it like this...

```
container.Register<IUserStore<AppUser>>(RavenDatabase.UserStore);
```

With a method defined as such...

```
public static UserStore<AppUser> UserStore() {
    // check to see if we even have a session factory to get a session from
    if (documentStore == null)
        OpenDatabase();

    return new UserStore<AppUser>(documentStore.OpenAsyncSession());
}
```

But I still continue to get the exception. I'm at a loss, here. This is my first time using Simple Injector.

## Stack Trace

#### System.InvalidOperationException

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession' while attempting to activate 'App.Identity.UserStore`1[App.Identity.AppUser]'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet<Type> callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet<Type> callSiteChain) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet<Type> callSiteChain) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet<Type> callSiteChain) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet<Type> callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet<Type> callSiteChain) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet<Type> callSiteChain) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet<Type> callSiteChain) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue, TArg>(ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, Func<TKey, TArg, TValue> valueFactory, TArg arg) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider) 
.lambda_method(Closure ) 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance() 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
```

#### SimpleInjector.ActivationException

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession' while attempting to activate 'App.Identity.UserStore`1[App.Identity.AppUser]'.
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance() 
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
```

#### System.InvalidOperationException

```
The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type LoginController failed. Unable to resolve service for type 'Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession' while attempting to activate 'App.Identity.UserStore`1[App.Identity.AppUser]'.
```

#### System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace with exception message of the exception and all inner exception.

Comment: Alright, I've added all of that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this problem is not related to Simple Injector. From your registrations, and the exception information I see the following is the case:

- You are resolving a `LoginController` from Simple Injector.
- This `LoginController` depends on `Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession`.
- `IAsyncDocumentSession` is cross-wired from the ASP.NET configuration system to Simple Injector using `CrossWire<IAsyncDocumentSession>`.
- `IAsyncDocumentSession` is registered in the ASP.NET configuration system.
- The implementation of `IAsyncDocumentSession` that is registered in ASP.NET depends on `UserStore<AppUser>`.
- The ASP.NET configuration system is unable to resolve that `IAsyncDocumentSession` registration and throws the exception stating:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Raven.Client.IAsyncDocumentSession' while attempting to activate 'App.Identity.UserStore`1[App.Identity.AppUser]'.

In other words, you would get the same exception when you would either resolve `LoginController` or `IAsyncDocumentSession` from the ASP.NET configuration system. Just call one of the following methods and you will see the same error:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<LoginController>();
// or
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IAsyncDocumentSession>();
```

I think that the `IAsyncDocumentSession` implementation depends on `UserStore<T>` or `IUserStore<T>`, but you haven't registered it in the ASP.NET configuration system.

Comment: I've tried changing up the order, and I still yield the same results unfortunately.

Comment: @Ciel, I didn't say anything about changing the order. I said that the registration *is probably missing* from the ASP.NET configuration. So you probably need to add a `services.AddTransient<IUserStore<AppUser>>(RavenDatabase.UserStore);` or something similar.

Comment: Alright, I did that, and now it is balking at `UserManager<AppUser>` needing `IUserStore<AppUser>`. I'm just so lost, none of this makes any sense to me. It was so much easier back before Microsoft added all this built-in stuff.

Comment: @Ciel "It was so much easier back before Microsoft added all this built-in stuff.". Yes, I agree.

Comment: Alright, I tried all of this and it then started to whine about the `UserManager` not getting the `Options` it needed. As far as I know, those are generated by the default Identity system, so I'm unsure what to do for injecting them.

Comment: @Ciel seems you're missing some common configuration. I might be mistaken, but all this stuff should probably be registered in the ASP.NET configuration system by default by Identity.

Comment: I'm lost. I thought I can't use Identity and a third party IoC at the same time?